# MySQL connection error node.js events.js 182

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am new to node.js I had originally planned to use PHP but wanted to gain experience with node. 
I am trying to connect to MySQL database using Node.js  when trying to connect I get the following error.

Thanks for the help!!

Here is the JS code

```
    var mysql = require('mysql')
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'lcoleman0422', 
    password:'Micheal4',
    database:'Top Level', 
    port:3306
});


con.connect();
   /* function(err){
    if (err) throw err
    con.query('select * from Customer',function(error,result){
        if(error)throw  error;
        console.log(result[0].First_Name);
        }
    )
});*/
```

con.end();

This is the code from my MYSQL_Connection.js

```
Connected
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/lcoleman0422/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:113:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/lcoleman0422/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
lcoleman0422@p3plcpnl0867 [~/public_html/js]$
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect.

Comment: I have edited the question please let me know if you have any issues with it. Thanks for the help

Comment: I guess your problem is you are closing connection, immediately after connecting it.

Comment: correct I am not sure why its doing so.  Faulty mysql package?

Comment: Check MySQL server logfiles to see if there's a reason why the server is closing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code let know if you have any doubts this.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'lcoleman0422',
    password: 'Micheal4',
    database: 'Top Level'
});

connection.connect();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(SELECT * FROM Customer, (error, data) => {
        if(error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            res.json(data[0].First_Name)
        } 
    });
});
```